# I have written a neural network model, but it's accuracy only increases when the weights take certain values

Tags: python

So basically, if the weights, which are initially assigned randomly, are within a range, of about 0.4 to -0.4 for w0 for example, then they will change and the accuracy will improve. However, if the weights are assigned a random number that is outside this range, then they won't be changed at all. I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be great :)

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class NN_model:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.w0 = np.random.randn()
        self.w1 = np.random.randn()
        self.bias = np.random.randn()
        self.trained = False

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoid_p(self, x):
        return self.sigmoid(x) * (1 - self.sigmoid(x))

    def calculate_loss(self, pred, target):
        loss = np.square(target - pred)
        return loss

    def training_loop(self, data):
        costs = []
        learning_rate = 0.005
        print(self.w0)
        if self.trained == True:
            print('Model already trained')
            pass
        else:
            for i in range(50):
                for i in range(100000):
                    ri = np.random.randint(len(data))
                    point = data[ri]

                    sig_out = ((self.w0 * point[0]) + (self.w1 * point[1]) + self.bias)
                    pred = self.sigmoid(sig_out)

                    cost = self.calculate_loss(pred, point[2])
                    costs.append(cost)
                    dcost_dpred = 2 * (pred - point[2])
                    dpred_dsigout = self.sigmoid_p(sig_out)
                    dsigout_dw0 = point[0]
                    dsigout_dw1 = point[1]
                    dsigout_dbias = 1

                    dcost_dw0 = dcost_dpred * dpred_dsigout * dsigout_dw0
                    dcost_dw1 = dcost_dpred * dpred_dsigout * dsigout_dw1
                    dcost_dbias = dcost_dpred * dpred_dsigout * dsigout_dbias

                    self.w0 += - learning_rate * dcost_dw0
                    self.w1 += - learning_rate * dcost_dw0
                    self.bias += - learning_rate * dcost_dbias


                print(self.w0, self.w1, self.bias)
                #-0.0752623452445784 0.2447376547554179 4.032995041915469
                #-0.3042823068224879 0.015717693177505765 18.643149928253827

            self.trained = True
        plt.plot(costs)
        plt.show()


    def predict(self, test_data):
        if self.trained == True:
            pred = self.sigmoid( (test_data[0] * self.w0) + (test_data[1] * self.w1) + self.bias )
            print(pred)
            if pred > 0.5:
                print('Woman')
            else:
                print('Man')
        else:
            print('Error: Model has not been trained yet')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have intuitive understanding of how the neural networks work behind the scene. There is no rule of thumb to decide the best values for your weights.

It might be possible that your initial weights pulls your near to accuracy really fast but in your example it might seem that while taking weights in a wide range with learning rate = 0.005, it will take some time until your weights are reduced. Therefore learning rates also play crucial role. Try tweaking that as well.